# How do I escape a single quote in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, escaping

I am trying to use the escape function to escape a single quote:

```
var tagDesc = "Workers'_Compensation";
tagDesc = escape(tagDesc);
$("#" + tagDesc + ".tag").css("display", "none");
```

The escape function replaces the single quote with `%27` to `"Workers%27_Compensation"`.

So I get an error,

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Workers%27_Compensation.tag

Comment: str = JSON.stringify(String(str));
str = str.substring(1, str.length-1);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **backslash**

`"Workers\'_Compensation";`

Inside a selector you would **require 2 of them**  `"Workers\\'_Compensation";`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ywr/5/)**

Comment: Note that in the string literal what you're actually escaping is the backslash, so that the string created from the literal ends up with a one backslash followed by a single-quote.

Comment: You are right! My problem was with ASP.Net. I was trying to add the JQuery script on server side. But  DR["VarDesc"].ToString().Replace("'", "\\'") wouldn't let me add the backslash. On further search I found that I should use  DR["VarDesc"].ToString().Replace("'", @"\\'").

Comment: You don't need _three_ backslashes in a row. `\\'` is enough. The single-quote doesn't need escaping in the string literal because the literal is quoted with doubles. You just need the resulting string that is used as a jQuery selector to contain one backslash before the single-quote, and your original version with `\\'` did that. My previous comment was just to point out what your answer was doing, not to get you to change it...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is JavaScript and to escape a special character you can use **backslash**.

With `\` you can escape `'` 
Try this:

```
var tagDesc = "Workers\\'_Compensation";
tagDesc = escape(tagDesc);
$("#" + tagDesc + ".tag").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: But string literals `"Workers\'_Compensation"` and `"Workers'_Compensation"` produce the same string...