# Set style of element being added with .before() when a variable is needed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating an element using the jQuery function .before() as so:

```
d.children().first().before("<div class='test-div'><span class='test-span'>" + text + "</span></div>")
```

I'm trying to set the style of the span which is all fine by just adding a style='left:10px' attribute right after the class, however I need the pixel count to be a variable so it would look something like this:

```
"...style='"left" + leftOffset'..."
```

However, since the .before() function requires the use of the double quotes (" ") this is not working. I tried using .style() after .before() but i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.children(...).first(...).before(...).style is not a function
```

Is there a solution to this that I'm missing or will I need to apply the style in some other way?

Others thought this was a duplicate question, but the linked question is quite inherently different. I didn't need to escape a single quote. Basically I needed to use a third set of quotes inside two sets.

Comment: Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845869/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845869/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845869/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-jquery)

Comment: Not quite. I didn't need to use the escape character \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand where the problem lies.

```
d.children().first().before("<div class='test-div'><span class='test-span' style='" + (left + leftOffset) + "'>" + text + "</span></div>")
```

should work just fine.

Comment: style='left:" + leftOffset + "' ended up being what I needed which I thought I tried, but apparently not. Thank you!